# How to consume changes to Google Cloud Datastore as a stream?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

The [Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) page implicates that this would be possible, but I haven't found a way of observing change events in the Google Cloud Datastore docs. How is it done?

[image]

Comment: I think you probably can setup a pub/sub as the intermediate service. Operations on the datastore serve as publisher and thus publish messages to a topic. The datasflow streaming would be a subscriber in this case. I never tried this though.

Comment: I gave up on Datastore for my needs. I haven't seen any document mention what you suggest. Google Cloud Storage, however, has pub/sub integration (and I'm currently looking at it).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, the integration of Cloud Datastore with Dataflow is through DatastoreIO (now based on [DatastoreV1](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/datastore/DatastoreV1.html)), which can only be used as a bounded source for batch jobs.

I have been trying to find an alternative solution that would allow you to use Datastore (directly or indirectly) as an unbounded source (for instance creating a Pub/Sub topic where Datastore changes are published and can be consumed from Dataflow), but I do not think that would be a viable solution given that, as you said, there is no easy way to detect changes (addition of entities, modification of entities, etc.) in Datastore.

For now, I have filed an internal request to improve the documentation to either modify the image so that it does not imply that Cloud Datastore can be used with a Streaming Pipeline, or clarify this use case.

Comment: so one must use the api to directly publish messages any time we suspect there is a change?
I've seen cloud functions that trigger - would a hack be to publish an message via the cloud function?